# Кодирование изображения в Base64 на Java

Tags: java, base64

Необходимо на Java сделать конвертер изображения сохраненного на компьютере(jpg или png) в строку Base64.
Можете посоветовать готовое решение, или хороший материал по этому поводу, очень желательно на русском?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подозреваю, что Вам может помочь http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html